# jQuery fadeOut to percent

Tags: jquery, fadeout

How to create fadeOut to only 20% or 30% visible? Because fadeOut remove my element from DOM. I want to create image animation with fadeOut and fadeIn.

```
var about = $("#about");
    about.mouseenter(function() {
            about.fadeOut("fast", function() {
            about.attr('src', 'img/about1.png');
            about.fadeIn('slow', function() {   
            });
        });
    about.mouseout(function () {
            about.fadeOut("fast", function () {
            about.attr('src', 'img/about.png')
            about.fadeIn("slow");
            });
        });   
    });
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/

Answer (score 3):

Use jQuery fadeTo, so as you can specify the opacity you want to fade to ([API](https://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/))

```
$("#about").fadeTo( "slow" , 0.5);
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery includes a [`fadeTo()`](https://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/) function.

```
about.fadeTo("fast", 0.2, function() {
    about.attr('src', 'img/about1.png');
    about.fadeIn('slow', function() {  });
});
```

The first parameter is for the speed of the transition, the second the opacity (any value between `0` and `1`, so `0.2` = 20%), and the third is the callback function.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use animate function

```
$(el).animate({"opacity":"0.6"}, 500);
```

Comment: you can also do that with css transitions